# How to write general-type queue library in c?

Tags: c, templates, generics, queue, polymorphism

I have a struct that stores fixed size (15) and fixed type (integer).

```
typedef struct Queue Queue;
struct Queue
{
    int buffer[15];    //only store 15 integer 
    int head;
    int space;
    int tail;
    int (*isFull)(Queue_int* const me);
    int (*isEmpty)(Queue_int* const me);
    int (*getSize)(Queue_int* const me);
    void (*insert)(Queue_int* const me, int k);    //insert integer only
    int (*remove)(Queue_int* const me);
};
```

I want to write a general queue library. In other words, a queue struct for any type and any size.

I tried macro to tackle this problem. That is, I created a general interface for other interfaces.

```
/*queue.h*/

#define Queue_Define(type, size)\
  typedef struct Queue_##type Queue_##type;\
  struct Queue_##type \
  { \
    type buffer[size]; \
    int head; \
    int space; \
    int tail; \
    int (*isFull)(Queue_##type* const me); \
    int (*isEmpty)(Queue_##type* const me);  \
    int (*getSize)(Queue_##type* const me);  \
    void (*insert)(Queue_##type* const me, type k); \
    int (*remove)(Queue_##type* const me); \
  }\
```

But then I came across another problem that **client has no idea how to use queue.h** in that struct name is created by macro other then client itself.

For example:

```
/*queue_employee.h*/

#include "queue.h"

Queue_Define(employee, 15);

void Queue_employee_Init
(
    Queue_employee* const me,    //oops! how do client know struct name is Queue_employee?
    int (*isFullfunction)(Queue_employee* const me),    //ditto
    int (*isEmptyfunction)(Queue_employee* const me),    //ditto
    int (*getSizefunction)(Queue_employee* const me),    //ditto
    void (*insertfunction)(Queue_employee* const me, employee k),    //ditto
    int (*removefunction)(Queue_employee* const me)    //ditto
);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly asking: Is this for somekind of assignment?

Comment: @Ackdari What do you mean by assignment? I learnt good programmers write good libraries, and I want to be a good programmer. That's all.

Comment: @AndyLin he means homework.

Comment: @Jabberwocky No. It's not a homework.

Comment: I do not really get, why you are not trying to create struct in header file directly and instead you use macro? Then, create struct object in main, and pass pointer of it to the function with needed arguments

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli In such case, I'm writing my own source code, not a library. If other people want to use queue, they need to copy my code, re-write it (change type to their own), and paste to their code.

Comment: Note: `Queue_Define(long long, size)` will not work with `Queue_##type* const me`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more or less fancy ways that you can make generic interfaces with macros, but I'd recommend to start with the "old school" way of generic programming in C, which means using `void*` in combination with size variables.

First some notes about your current code:

- I'd drop the "member function" syntax from the struct, since it's simply not meaningful in C. `foo.isFull(foo)` is not the slightest more user-friendly than `queue_isFull(foo)`. The function pointers add nothing but needless complexity. If C supported a `this` pointer like C++, it would be another story. But it does not, so there's nothing gained from trying to emulate C++ style syntax.
- `const` qualifying the pointer arguments with `Queue_int* const queue` is not a meaningful API. The caller doesn't care what your function does internally with your local variable `queue`. Have it point wherever you like - the caller doesn't care. I believe you are actually mistaking this syntax for *const correctness*, which is good and correct practice. You should then have written `int isFull(const Queue_int* queue)` which means that the function `isFull` won't modify the pointed-at queue, which makes perfect sense.
- You should consider using private encapsulation. The caller should not be allowed to access members like `buffer` directly. This becomes even more important if we start using `void*`, because they are type unsafe. We can achieve private encapsulation with the concept of *opaque types*.

Opaque type goes like this:

```
// queue.h
typedef struct queue_t queue_t;
```

This is a forward declaration of a structure. The user who includes queue.h won't be able to access members inside the struct, nor to declare an instance of the struct. They will only be able to work with pointers to the struct. (It works exactly like an abstract base class in C++ if that concept is familiar.) The actual struct declaration will only be visible to the private .c file.

Next up you'd drop a number of available functions in the header, including a "constructor" and "destructor". For example:

```
queue_t* queue_init (size_t item_size, size_t def_queue_size);
void queue_delete (queue_t* queue);

bool queue_set_item (queue_t* queue, size_t index, const void* item);
bool queue_get_item (const queue_t* queue, size_t index, void* item);
```

Let the caller provide pointers and sizes so that it becomes type-generic. (I'm just making some nonsense member functions here, ignoring that this is a queue data type.)

The full header would look like this:

```
// queue.h
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct queue_t queue_t;

queue_t* queue_init (size_t item_size, size_t def_queue_size);
void queue_delete (queue_t* queue);

bool queue_set_item (queue_t* queue, size_t index, const void* item);
bool queue_get_item (const queue_t* queue, size_t index, void* item);

#endif /* QUEUE_H */
```

And then a matching C file with the implementation of the struct as well as the functions:

```
// queue.c
#include "queue.h"

struct queue_t
{
  size_t  item_size;
  size_t  queue_size;
  uint8_t data[];
};

queue_t* queue_init (size_t item_size, size_t def_queue_size)
{
  queue_t* result = malloc (sizeof *result + item_size*def_queue_size);
  if(result == NULL)
    return NULL;

  result->item_size  = item_size;
  result->queue_size = def_queue_size;
  memset(result->data, 0, item_size*def_queue_size);

  return result;
}

void queue_delete (queue_t* queue)
{
  free(queue);
}

bool queue_set_item (queue_t* queue, size_t index, const void* item)
{
  if(index >= queue->queue_size)
    return false;

  memcpy(&queue->data[index * queue->item_size], item, queue->item_size);

  return true;
}
```

Example of caller code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(void) 
{
  queue_t* int_queue = queue_init(sizeof(int), 10);
  int x = 666;
  int y;
  (void) queue_set_item(int_queue, 5, &x);
  (void) queue_get_item(int_queue, 5, &y);
  printf("%d\n", y);
  queue_delete(int_queue);

  queue_t* string_queue = queue_init(sizeof(char[10]), 10);
  char str1[10] = "Hello";
  char str2[10];
  (void) queue_set_item(string_queue, 3, str1);
  (void) queue_get_item(string_queue, 3, str2);
  puts(str2);
  queue_delete(string_queue);

  return 0;
}
```

This of course just a silly artificial example and nothing like a queue ADT, but hopefully you get the idea of how to implement one, type-generic.

Comment: Would you please explain why you prefer `sizeof(*result)` over `sizeof(queue_t)` in queue_init?

Comment: @AndyLin It's just coding style. Some may argue that it minimizes the chance of mistakes in case the type of `result` would change later. Either style is fine, really.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use a queue that just holds `void*` as it's content. Also you can eliminate the size restriction by exchaning the underlaying array with a bigger one if necessary:

```c
typedef struct Queue {
    void** content;
    int head;
    int space;
    int tail;
    int entries;
} Queue_t

void Queue_init(Queue_t* const queue, int init_size) {
    queue->space = init_size;
    queue->content = calloc(sizeof(void*), init_size);
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
    queue->entries = 0;
}

void insert(struct Queue* const queue, void* entry) {
    if (queue->entries == queue->space) {
        // alloc new array
        int add = queue->space / 2 == 0 ? 1 : queue->space / 2;
        void** tmp = calloc(sizeof(void*), queue->space + add);

        // copy the old content to the new array
        int tmp_i = 0
        if (queue->head < queue->tail) {
            // can copy all in one go
            for (int i = queue->head; i < queue->tail; i++) {
                tmp[tmp_i] = queue->content[i];
                tmp_i++;
            }
        } else {
            // content oveflow from the end of the array to the begining
            for (int i = queue->head; i < queue->space; i++) {
                tmp[tmp_i] = queue->content[i];
                tmp_i++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < queue->tail; i++) {
                tmp[tmp_i] = queue->content[i];
                tmp_i++;
            }
        }

        free(queue->content);
        // set the new content and head and tail accordingly
        queue->content = tmp;
        queue->head = 0;
        queue->tail = queue->entries;
    }

    // put the new entry at it's place and adjust tail
    queue->content[queue->tail] = entriy;
    queue->entries++;
    queue->tail = (queue->tail + 1) % queue->space;
}

// all other functions ...
```